Why is my image not loading properly in my NPM React Package
I am developing a React component library for a Phone Frameset that holds screenshots of apps.
I'll provide the files with the project structure right now. Maybe the issue is from one of the config files or the URL
|- dist
|----|- components
|----|----|- PhoneFrame.d.ts
|----|- assets
|----|----|- iPhone14ProFrame.png
|----|- index.d.ts
|----|- index.js
|- node_modules
|- src
|----|- assets
|----|----|- iPhone14ProFrame.png
|----|- components
|----|----|- PhoneFrame.tsx
|----|- styles
|----|----|- styles.css
|----|- declaration.d.ts
|----|- index.tsx
|- .eslintrc.json
|- .gitignore
|- .nvmrc
|- babel.config.json
|- LICENSE
|- package-lock.json
|- package.json
|- README.md
|- tsconfig.json
|- webpack.config.mjs

PhoneFrame.d.ts:
import React from 'react';
import '../styles/styles.css';
interface PhoneFrameProps {
    screenshotList: string[];
}
export default function PhoneFrame({ screenshotList }: PhoneFrameProps): React.JSX.Element;
export {};

index.js:
import PhoneFrame from "./components/PhoneFrame";
export default PhoneFrame;

.eslintrc.json:
{
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:react/recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"
  ],
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 2020,
    "sourceType": "module",
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true
    }
  },
  "settings": {
    "react": {
      "version": "detect"
    }
  },
  "rules": {
    "react/prop-types": "off"
  }
}

babel.config.json:
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "modules": false,
        "targets": {
          "node": "current"
        }
      }
    ],
    "@babel/preset-react",
    "@babel/preset-typescript" 
  ],
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        "@babel/preset-react",
        "@babel/preset-typescript"
      ],
      "plugins": [
        [
          "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
          {
            "spec": true
          }
        ]
      ]
    }
  },
  "plugins": [
    [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
      {
        "spec": true
      }
    ],
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread"
  ]
}

package.json:
{
  "name": "react-framify",
  "version": "1.1.14",
  "description": "A React component library for device framesets",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "build-babel": "babel src --out-dir dist --presets=@babel/preset-react,@babel/preset-env",
    "build-webpack": "webpack --config webpack.config.mjs",
    "build-ts": "tsc",
    "build": "npm run build-ts && npm run build-babel && npm run build-webpack",
    "test": "echo 'Error: no test specified' && exit 1",
    "dev": "nodemon ./bin/www"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/CodeNKoffee/react-framify.git"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "react",
    "framify",
    "component",
    "library"
  ],
  "author": "Hatem Soliman hatemthedev@gmail.com",
  "license": "GPL-3.0",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/CodeNKoffee/react-framify/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://react-framify.netlify.app/",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.10.5",
    "@babel/core": "^7.23.9",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.20.7",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object": "^7.21.11",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-jsx": "^7.23.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.23.9",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.23.3",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.24.7",
    "@types/react": "^18.3.3",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.3.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.3",
    "css-loader": "^6.10.0",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.24.0",
    "image-webpack-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "nodemon": "^3.1.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.4",
    "ts-loader": "^9.2.6",
    "typescript": "4.9.5",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1"
  }
}

tsconfig.json:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": true,
    "emitDeclarationOnly": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "jsx": "react",
    "allowJs": true,
    "checkJs": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.tsx"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}

webpack.config.mjs:
import path from 'path';

export default {
  mode: 'production',
  entry: './src/index.tsx',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve('dist'),
    filename: 'index.js',
    library: {
      type: 'umd',
      name: 'ReactFramify',
    },
    globalObject: 'this',
    publicPath: '/',
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx'],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'ts-loader',
            options: {
              transpileOnly: true,
            },
          },
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              presets: ['@babel/preset-react', '@babel/preset-env'],
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: 'babel-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg)$/,
        type: 'asset/resource',
        generator: {
          filename: 'assets/[name][ext]',
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
    ],
  },
  externals: {
    react: 'react',
    'react-dom': 'react-dom',
  },
};

declaration.d.ts:
declare module 'PhoneFrame' {
  const PhoneFrame: React.ComponentType<any>;
  export default PhoneFrame;
}

declare module "*.png" {
  const value: string;
  export default value;
}

declare module "*.css" {
  const content: { [className: string]: string };
  export default content;
}

index.tsx:
"use client"

import PhoneFrame from "./components/PhoneFrame";

export default PhoneFrame;

PhoneFrame.tsx:
"use client"

import React, { useEffect, useState, TouchEvent } from 'react';
import PhoneFrameset from '../assets/iPhone14ProFrame.png';
import '../styles/styles.css';

interface PhoneFrameProps {
  screenshotList: string[];
}

export default function PhoneFrame({ screenshotList }: PhoneFrameProps) {
  const [currentImageIndex, setCurrentImageIndex] = useState<number>(0);
  const [initialTouchPosition, setInitialTouchPosition] = useState<number | null>(null);
  const [fadeOut, setFadeOut] = useState<boolean>(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setCurrentImageIndex(0);
  }, [screenshotList]);

  const handleTouchStart = (e: TouchEvent) => {
    const touch = e.touches[0];
    setInitialTouchPosition(touch.clientX);
  };

  const handleTouchMove = (e: TouchEvent) => {
    if (initialTouchPosition === null) return;

    const touch = e.touches[0];
    const currentTouchPosition = touch.clientX;
    const touchDistance = currentTouchPosition - initialTouchPosition;

    if (touchDistance > 50) {
      showPreviousImage();
    } else if (touchDistance < -50) {
      showNextImage();
    }
  };

  const handleTouchEnd = () => {
    setInitialTouchPosition(null);
  };

  const showPreviousImage = () => {
    setFadeOut(true);
    setTimeout(() => {
      setCurrentImageIndex((prevIndex) =>
        prevIndex === 0 ? screenshotList.length - 1 : prevIndex - 1
      );
      setFadeOut(false);
    }, 300);
  };

  const showNextImage = () => {
    setFadeOut(true);
    setTimeout(() => {
      setCurrentImageIndex((prevIndex) =>
        prevIndex === screenshotList.length - 1 ? 0 : prevIndex + 1
      );
      setFadeOut(false);
    }, 300);
  };

  return (
    <figure
      className="phone__frameset--wrapper preview__phone--mockup"
      onTouchStart={handleTouchStart}
      onTouchMove={handleTouchMove}
      onTouchEnd={handleTouchEnd}
    >
      <img src={PhoneFrameset} alt="Image by svstudioart on Freepik" className="phone__frameset" />
      <img
        src={screenshotList[currentImageIndex]}
        className={`phone__frameset--img ${fadeOut ? 'fade-out' : ''}`}
      />
      <div className="preview__scroll--btns">
        <button className="preview__scroll--btn btn" onClick={showPreviousImage}>Previous</button>
        <button className="preview__scroll--btn btn" onClick={showNextImage}>Next</button>
      </div>
    </figure>
  );
}

.nvmrc:
20.15.0

Preview of how one of my projects is using my library but the frameset is not loading causing the buttons to be also misplaced.

I also tried in the webpack.config.mjs to remove the specific generator, but it didn;t work:
{
   test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg)$/,
   type: 'asset/resource',
},

When installing the package after deleting the old dist and npm run build on a new project I get the screenshots provided by myself as a prop but the PhoneFrameset not. I check the project strucutre, & url paths, but none seemed to be the issue.
